# Can a Title bar can be placed in the center of the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface

I mean There is bar with title in the center and close button in the left side and another button on the right side. Is it possible to place that bar in the center of the screen horizontally ?? Like that bar will take care of the screen below it and will not care about the content above it .

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches you can take (the numbers I am using are just approximate so that you can get an idea):

### Create a navbar in the center of the screen

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 250.0, 320.0, 40.0);
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

But this is the preferred way:

### Create a navigation controller occupying the bottom half of the screen

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 250.0, 320.0, 230.0);
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```